# Clone/copy definition of MIB leaf into another MIB tree

Tags: mib

I have MIB file with definitions of four traps

```
.1.3.6.1.4.1.5591.1.0.0  (SCTE-HMS-COMMON-MIB::hmsColdStart)
.1.3.6.1.4.1.5591.1.0.1  (SCTE-HMS-ALARMS-MIB::hmsAlarmEvent)
.1.3.6.1.4.1.5591.1.0.2  (SCTE-HMS-COMMON-MIB::hmsWarmStart)
.1.3.6.1.4.1.5591.1.0.3  (SCTE-HMS-DOWNLOAD-MIB::hmsDownloadStatus)
```

But my appliances sends the following traps

```
.1.3.6.1.4.1.7465.20.2.6.0.0
.1.3.6.1.4.1.7465.20.2.6.0.1
.1.3.6.1.4.1.7465.20.2.6.0.2
.1.3.6.1.4.1.7465.20.2.6.0.3
```

These correspond to the above traps based on the last digit. The prefix successfully resolves into a vendor-specific object, because I have a matching MIB from the vendor of my appliance. Hence, what I get is

```
WISI-HEADEND-ROOT-MIB::headendMib.0
WISI-HEADEND-ROOT-MIB::headendMib.1
WISI-HEADEND-ROOT-MIB::headendMib.2
WISI-HEADEND-ROOT-MIB::headendMib.3
```

Now the question: Can I append the `WISI-HEADEND-ROOT-MIB` by the definitions of the traps without copying the complete definition? Unfortunately, I have no experiences in writing a MIB, because I never had to do it before. What I am looking for is somehting like

```
wisiColdStart  TRAP-TYPE
    CLONE EVERYTHING FROM SCTE-HMS-COMMON-MIB::hmsColdStart
    ::= 0
wisiAlarmEvent  TRAP-TYPE
    CLONE EVERYTHING FROM SCTE-HMS-COMMON-MIB::hmsAlarmEvent
    ::= 1
wisiWarmStart  TRAP-TYPE
    CLONE EVERYTHING FROM SCTE-HMS-COMMON-MIB::hmsWarmStart
    ::= 2
wisiDownloadStatus  TRAP-TYPE
    CLONE EVERYTHING FROM SCTE-HMS-COMMON-MIB::hmsDownloadStatus
    ::= 3
```

Is somehing like this possible?